# How to run code against the Quartz.NET server?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm new to Quartz.NET and have a simple question. I downloaded the Quartz.NET-2.2 server on my machine. There isn't much documentation on how to use it. I started the server by clicking on Quartz.Server.exe and would like to run Example 1 (HelloJob.cs and SimpleExample.cs) against it. How do I do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you read the tutorial. http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I did and also created and ran several projects in Visual Studio to learn how to code a task scheduler. My question is how to move what I implemented to the Quartz.NET server and how to create or update the quartz_jobs.xml. I was unable to find the info I want at quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html.

Answer (score 5):

I found this document, http://jayvilalta.com/quartznetbook/QuartzNetQuickstart.pdf. It's a lifesaver. The document answers most of my questions and also provides examples that can be run with the server.  Hope this will help others who are looking for the same kind of information.